# Double integral discontinuity question

Tags: multivariable-calculus

In lecture we were doing the problem $\int {1 \over \sqrt{xy}}\,dxdy$ over the region $[0,1] \times [0,1]$.

Since the function is undefined when $x=0$ or $y=0$ we took the limit as $\delta,\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ of
$$
\int_{\delta}^{1-\delta} \int_{\epsilon}^{1-\epsilon}{1 \over \sqrt{xy}}\,dxdy.
$$

I understand why this works; however, why couldn't we just evaluate the limit as $\delta,\epsilon \rightarrow 0$
$$
\int_{\delta}^{1} \int_{\epsilon}^{1}{1 \over \sqrt{xy}}\,dxdy
$$
since the function is well defined at $x=1,y=1$?

Comment: I think both are correct. I would have done as you suggest.